# Showing that $a\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: inequality

Let: $$a= \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$ such that n is a natural number. The problem is to show that: $$a\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$.
My approach: I could show that: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\ge\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2}$, so if I could show that $$a\le\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2}$$ it'd be done.
Any hint or help are much appreciated

Comment: Hint: multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x$. This is a common trick when working with differences of radicals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$ a=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}$$
Since $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\ge2\sqrt n$, you get $a\le \frac1{2\sqrt n}$.

Comment: Aha, I see now, thank you so much both of you!

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (n, n+1)$ such that $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{c}} \leq \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$ where the last inequality comes from the fact that $\sqrt{.}$ is non-decreasing.